# awstats does not log connections from java app

Tags: logging, awstats

We have a working installed awstats, it shows all the requests from web browsers, but it seems  it's not reporting connections done from a java desktop app. Apache log does show them but neither the awstats html reporting file nor the database file in DirData have them

The LogType in config file is W (web) and the requests done from the app are http GET's.

This kind of request appears on the report:

```
XXX.XX.XX.XXX - - [19/Jul/2010:11:16:21 +0200] "GET /wms/urb?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities HTTP/1.1" 200 6813 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.99 Safari/533.4"
```

But this does not:

```
XXX.XX.XX.XXX - - [16/Jul/2010:08:17:23 +0200] "GET /wms/urb?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&EXCEPTIONS=XML HTTP/1.1" 200 7751 "-" "Java/1.6.0_18"
```

Can awstats report this type of access or is better to use another tool?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in this link: [Analyzing Eclipse Update Site Traffic with AWStats](http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/02/analyzing-eclipse-update-site-traffic-with-awstats.html)

> In its' default configuration, AWStats
> will not present correct Update Site
> statistics. The main reason for that
> is the browser identity. When Eclipse
> connects to your site, it will
> identify itself as a "Java" agent, not
> as a browser. This causes AWStats to
> assume your client is a bot or a worm
> and ignore its' traffic
>
> ...
>
> Look for a setting called
> LevelForRobotsDetection, the default
> is 2, change it to 0. This will ensure
> the requests from the Java clients
> will not be detected as robots.

Replace Eclipse with whatever java app and there it is